# open 2 USB cameras simultaneously on VLC player Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, camera, vlc, vmware-fusion

How I open a Camera:
In terminal (text after the $ prompt = commands that I type):**_________________**

```
$ ls /dev/video*
/dev/video0  /dev/video1
$ vlc v4l2:///dev/video0
VLC media player 2.0.8 Twoflower (revision 2.0.8a-0-g68cf50b)
[0x9f2d908] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
```

VLC starts playing camera output.

In another new terminal (BOLD = commands that I type):

```
$ vlc v4l2:///dev/video1
VLC media player 2.0.8 Twoflower (revision 2.0.8a-0-g68cf50b)
[0x9b24908] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[0xb0500960] v4l2 demux error: VIDIOC_STREAMON failed
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
[0xb0501188] v4l2 access error: cannot set input 0: Device or resource busy
[0xb0501188] v4l2 access error: cannot set input 0: Device or resource busy
[0xb5300618] main input error: open of `v4l2:///dev/video1' failed
```

No video is played, only error message.

Primary Objective: I want to open two cameras simultaneously in opencv (c++) ... got similar errors with opencv .. so I'm using VLC Player to debug the issue.
The errors when opening two cameras simultaneously using c++ opencv ( the code is similar to https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/starter_video.cpp?rev=4705 )

```
e557822@e557822-T740:~/Desktop/Camera/starter_video2$ ls /dev/video*
/dev/video0  /dev/video1  /dev/video2
e557822@e557822-T740:~/Desktop/Camera/starter_video2$ ./starter_video2 0 1
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
press space to save a picture. q or esc to quit
init done 
opengl support available 
libv4l2: error turning on stream: No space left on device
VIDIOC_STREAMON: No space left on device
```

UPDATE 7/24 :
This Ubuntu 12.04 (32- bit) is a guest OS running on VMware Fusion. The host OS here is OSX 10.9.4 running on a Mac Pro computer hardware.

```
$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=HID, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=hub, Driver=hub/7p, 12M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 0, Class='bInterfaceClass 0xe0 not yet handled', Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 1, Class='bInterfaceClass 0xe0 not yet handled', Driver=btusb, 12M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci_hcd/6p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 6, If 0, Class='bInterfaceClass 0x0e not yet handled', Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 6, If 1, Class='bInterfaceClass 0x0e not yet handled', Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 7, If 0, Class='bInterfaceClass 0x0e not yet handled', Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 7, If 1, Class='bInterfaceClass 0x0e not yet handled', Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
$
```

Answer (score 2):

This is USB bandwidth problem, not VLC one.

`VIDIOC_STREAMON: No space left on device` is message which is given when USB bandwidth is full.

Most modern USB cameras do high speed, high density image output. USB2 is limited to 480Mbps which is 60 megabytes/s theoretical. In practice all kind of overhead will use about half of it and 30 megabytes/s is maximum you can get. This means camera can send 1 megabyte image at 30fps.

All you can do is get motherboard with multiple USB buses. All small computers tend to have just one. High-end gaming motherboards have 2..3 USB2.0 buses. You can see it under linux:

```
$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 2, If 0, Class=scard, Driver=usbfs, 12M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci_hcd/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M
        |__ Port 5: Dev 3, If 0, Class='bInterfaceClass 0xe0 not yet handled', Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 5: Dev 3, If 1, Class='bInterfaceClass 0xe0 not yet handled', Driver=btusb, 12M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci_hcd/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=vend., Driver=rts5139, 480M
        |__ Port 5: Dev 4, If 0, Class='bInterfaceClass 0x0e not yet handled', Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 5: Dev 4, If 1, Class='bInterfaceClass 0x0e not yet handled', Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
$
```

Most probably both cameras are connected to same bus.

Other option is to reduct FPS speed or resolution. But this not always helping because I have seen cameras which reserve 80% of USB bandwidth anyway.

Comment: Please refer "UPDATE 7/24 :" at the bottom of the main post above. It has the results of lsusb -t

Comment: There is one USB2.0 bus only in this update (look for 480Mbps bus. This is 2.0.

Comment: How can I add 1 more bus in VMware fusion?

Comment: This is hardware, not VMware limitation I believe. Additional USB card may help.

Comment: The hardware is actually very powerful.. I tested it before doing things on the VMware. It's a Mac Pro Computer/Workstation. Earlier, on the Mac OS X, I installed opencv using Mac ports (with Python bindngs). I successfully opened the same 2 cameras using c++ code. I was also able to do the same using python code.

Comment: Whatever else is powerful, it does not help if you have single USB bus. And this is common case. It also depends on framerate, resolution and compression algorithm. I have investigated this topic extensively and made robot with 8 low resolution cameras connected to two USB2.0 buses. But single webcam in full resolution consumes one bus fully. If lsusb -t does not show over one bus, you are screwed.

Comment: Referring to the results of my lsusb -t. Can I move a camera from 1 root hub to another @Samuel